Name of non-standard perspective projection where parallel lines do not meet at a single vanishing point
I have made a non-standard perspective projection for a rectangular room (see left figure), in which for stylistic reasons, I chose to make the perspective "width" of the walls equal regardless of floor aspect ratio. This means that for a non-square room, the projection lines where the walls meet do not converge to a single vanishing point. Does this perspective projection have a name?

Just to add, I know that there are downsides to this perspective, chief of which is that objects that lie on a plane parallel to the floor do not retain their aspect ratios when they are above the floor, with the distortion getting worse the closer the object is to the ceiling. Note also that I chose to retain the aspect ratio of the floor in my non-standard projection, thus allowing the stretch/compression to affect e.g. the box representing the ceiling.

Then its not a perspective projection. Its unlikely to be a projection at all. But yeah i have seen (though rarely) old military maps that show all the facades of buildings in this way so that you can see all sides of the building form top as seen from street level

Thanks for the response. I feel it falls into perspective projection category due to its converging of parallel lines. Regarding the military maps,it's interesting to know this.

No, converging lines dont make thigs perspective projections. There does not need to be a single convergence in a perspective projection.
